# Creating tiling scheme to get multiple extents before gridding elevation data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, dem, gmt

Looking to create 1 degree by 1 degree tiles with pixel overlap to get extents before I start gridding. So basically I would like to have a shapefile of the tiling scheme with extents before having the grid. Just want a more automated processes than doing this "by hand".